# Colvis javascript create problems for toolbar ui in datatables & yadcf

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, yadcf

My table without Colvis.js have toolbar, [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/18/)

[image: toolbar]

But with Colvis.js toolbar disappears, [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/25/)

[image]

Using Firebug seems to be a conflict with jquery-ui but I don't understand well what exact happens. 
**Is a css problem or a javascript conflict?**
However this is relevant css for toolbar

```
<div class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix">
```

.

```
.ui-helper-clearfix::before, .ui-helper-clearfix::after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }
        .ui-helper-clearfix::after {
            clear: both;
        }
        .ui-helper-clearfix::before, .ui-helper-clearfix::after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr {
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        }
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl {
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        }
        .ui-widget-header {
            background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #cccccc;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            color: #222222;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ui-helper-clearfix {
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery dataTables sDom / dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is not very logic. You are right, it has to do with jQuery UI - you miss the `H` flag, which stands for *`jQueryUI theme "header" classes`*.

```
sDom: 'C<"H"lf>tip'
```

seems to be what you are looking for -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9nph3qah/**

`C`      - show Colvis, which are floated right
`<"H">`  - in jQuery UI header show
`l`   - Length menu
`f`   - Filter box (which also is floated right)
then
`t`      - Table
`i`      - Information
`p`      - Pagination

The very weird part is that you are expected to know that the ColVis button is floated to the right. The logic thing would be `sDom: '<"H"lfC>tip'` but this does not work, because the filter box also is floated to the right, and inserted first, and therefore get far most to the right ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/9nph3qah/1/))

In the above example I also remove the strange 1em margin-bottom the ColVis has by default :

```
div.ColVis {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

---

**Update**. As @user3520363 points out, it is a good idea to include the footer too :) Completely forgot that when focusing on the header.

```
sDom: 'C<"H"lf>t<"F"ip>'
```

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/41has856/**

Comment: just a little fix of your solution: `sDom: 'C<"H"lf>t<"F"ip>` so also footer element is visible :)

Comment: @user3520363, oh, you are right of course! Updated the answer with your correction.